# Flash Augmented Reality Virtual buttons

Tags: apache-flex

I'm working on Flash Augmented Reality. I want to add virtual buttons using FLAR MANAGER but can't do it. Anyone plzz help
thanx a lot in advance..!!  :)

Comment: seems like much explanation needed, what you really want to do. Do you want to add a button in your application ? or some thing like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/J0iRa.png

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdxxPhxQs_g&feature=relmfu  i want to do something like this

Answer (score 1):

FLAR Manager relies on one of 
FLARToolkit 
flare*tracker
flare*nft

see http://words.transmote.com/wp/flarmanager/

All 3 of these libraries are for tracking 2d "targets", not for tracking general motion.  None of them have the feature of tracking face or hand motions like the video clip.

If you are set on using Flash, you might be able to use Marilena, a Flash conversion of OpenCV that was floating around a couple of years ago.  However, the only demos I saw that used it were using it for face tracking, so I'm not sure whether it has other motion tracking in it or not.

http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000687.php#000687

A little google search for "eye toy for flash" gives me this "flytoy" library, really similar to your video.
http://www.zachernuk.com/2010/12/19/flash-eyetoy-with-source-code/